# Bootstrap 3 Navbar toggle Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar's toggle button refuses to work. The code I'm using has been copied and pasted from a Bootstrap template with a fully functional navbar. I don't know what's up.

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Name</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#portfolio">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#about">Downloads</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Here's the script tags to the JavaScript and jQuery files. They've been left unmodified.

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js" />

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" />
```

Comment: Please create a simple http server for web development.

Comment: What *exactly* isnt working?

Comment: @wahwahwah Here is an example of how the navbar should work: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/ (re-size the window to a mobile screen size to make the toggle button appear). The problem is that the button isn't doing anything when clicked.

Comment: i have exactly same problem.. did u find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't identify anything to drop down.  You need a list of things, using an unordered list.  All you have is the names of the buttons.  Please see bootstraps example below:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns

Comment: Sorry, I meant toggle button (as in the thing that shows and hides navbar contents on a small display). I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Can you send me a link to the template so I can review, the script as above also is not working for me.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean now.  Although I do not see a toggle button anywhere. It looks like it toggles only after it reaches a certain point in the scroll down, or one of the icons is selected under the main container.  You don't have enough of the original template, and maybe some additional javascript for it to work.  For some reason it won't download for me, but I'm sure that's what it is.